# For Buildfire app maker can python code be used?

Tags: python, buildfire

I'm using vgg face and require user input. Can python work in any way with Buildfire?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you add some more information to your question, maybe an example what you have tried, or what it is that you want to achieve? This makes it more clear what kind of answer to give. As it is the question is rather vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re creating a server side api call in Python, then no problem. If you want to build on top of the BuildFire.JS SDK for code to live on the phone, then it needs to be in JavaScript